# Show only submenus item with his parent menu item

Tags: php, joomla

I have the following menu in Joomla:

- Home
- Products

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3
- Services
- Contato

I created a menu module that show only the subitens:

- Product 1
- Product 2
- Product 3

But I would like to know hot to add the parent item "Product" in this menu:

- Products

  - Product 1
  - Product 2
  - Product 3

I can't create other menu because I can't put the same URL. Because this menu already is showing in top of page.

That is, I have this menu in a 'top' module, and I need a new menu (vertical) to help users to navigate.

Was I clear?

Can someone help me? I'm using Joomla 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second menu, choose a Menu Alias as the menu type, then pick the existing "Products" menu item from the list that appears.  When you do that, it essentially clones the one that already exists, but allows you to place and style it as you see fit.  When n clicked, it's the same url as the original one, just in a different location.

Comment: Thank you, worked. But there are one thing that I would like to improve... Joomla can't add a `class="active"` when clicked. I don't know why, cause other there's a `active` class when clicked.

Comment: Not sure about that, though it may well be a function of your template.  When I encounter those sorts of things, I enable Firebug, and use a default template to narrow down why it's not "working".

Comment: Seems to be a "bug" in Joomla, I see thi discussion: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=24634 but I tried all path files and don't still don't work. I will wait or try other time. The bigger problem is solved.